# Using a private domain or a new SAP for a new BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, custom-domain, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

We 're using a domain [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) with a business unit on a delegated domain as hub.mycompany.com.
As part of the work we have with one of our communities eg "Community" with a domain name [www.community.com](http://www.community.com), we would like to communicate with a sender profile such as @community.com
What would be the best recommandation to achieve this? Having a specific BU for "Community" contacts ? Purchashe a new SAP with a dedicated IP address or acquire a Private domain?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, using a top level domain as a sender domain in Marketing Cloud is possible, but comes with few limitations:

- You will not be able to use *community.com* as your SAP domain. This is due to the domain probably is being used for few existing purposes (e.g. the community website and corporate email). This leaves you with the option of using *hub.mycompany.com* as the SAP domain for this new BU.
- You can purchase *community.com* as a Private Domain, using it as a branded sender domain, while using *hub.mycompany.com* for branding links and image urls.
- While it is possible to use *community.com* as Private Domain, you will need to self-host the DNS settings, to allow for continued support of existing DNS entries.
- You will not be able to use the Reply Management in Marketing Cloud, as this would require you to have the domains MX records point to Marketing Cloud. Assuming MX records already take care of your corporate mailboxes for *community.com*.

My take on this would be to use same SAP domain (since community.com is related to mycompany.com, this will not raise many eyebrows), and also same IP address.

You will be able to purchase a Private Domain for *community.com*, allowing you to use this for branding your sender and Cloud Pages, etc. (however not links and image URLs), self hosting the DNS and refraining from using RMM in SFMC.

You can theoretically use a separate IP address for this new sender, but I expect the volumes to be lower than the monthly 100.000 which is required for maintaining a stable IP reputation for a dedicated IP address.